# Naudio buffer and realtime streaming

Tags: c#, naudio

My application is a text-to-speech application.
I develop a simple class based on NAudio to play the generated wave byte array (taht contains the text to be read). 
Here is my code:

```
private BufferedWaveProvider _bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(16000, 1));
private WaveOut _waveOut = new WaveOut();

public NAudioPlayer(){
_waveOut.Init(_bufferedWaveProvider);
_waveOut.Play();
}

public void Play(byte[] textBytes){
    _bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
    _bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
}
```

I do not know how to manage the buffer in order to prevent from full buffer exceptions.
Reading other posts, I thought about setting the buffer length but I do not what is the maximal size of the byte array (sent by another application).
More, I would like to avoid unexpected breaks when playing (so I think that using Thread.sleep to let the buffer discharging would not be a good idea...).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own class similar to the code in `BufferedWaveProvider`, but with a Queue of byte arrays. Each time you have a new bit of audio to play, then put it into the queue. Then in the `Read` method, return bytes from each queued buffer in turn, until you've reached the end of queued audio, and then return zeroes (it needs to be a never-ending stream, so `Read` must always return `count`). The only tricky bit will be keeping track of where you were up to reading, as it is likely that the number of bytes requested in the `Read` method will be less than the number of bytes available in a queued buffer.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure to understand all the solution. Could you please give me a tiny sample (even with incomplete code)? Thx